# looking for a very stable linux proxy

Tags: linux, proxy

I'm looking for a preferably small and **very stable** linux proxy. Nothing fancy. I've tried squid but its too bulky for what I need. Any recommendations?

Comment: web/http only? caching? What do you need the proxy to proxy, and what does it need to do with the data?  What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: just http. If it can do socks, ftp too that'd be great but not a priority.

Comment: @joe: what features are you looking for: logging? filtering? authentication? caching? rewriting? etc. And why is squid no good: needs too much CPU? too much RAM? too hard to configure? ...

Comment: all of the above for squid. Dont need logging, filtering, caching or rewriting. Authentication or ip control is necessary but i cant see a proxy developer not including access control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Squid is the standard proxy solution for Linux systems, and it's usually the best one.

You can disable logging, filtering, caching and rewriting by appropriately editing `squid.conf`, and the resulting system will be very small and fast (although even a little bit of caching usually helps a lot).

I think you should tinker with it a little more and try to configure it for your needs; Squid really is one of the best proxies around, and I don't see any better solution on Linux.

Comment: Totally agreed that squid is the best. Even some of the commercial proxy was based directly/indirectly to squid.

Its all depends on how you configure it.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of other light-weight proxies - e.g. tinyproxy, polipo and still come back to squid for sheer stability and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH with dynamic port forwarding? 
http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/ 
Give you an authentication method and is easy to setup with PuTTy or any ssh client.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at ClearOS - It's a CentOS based OS, runs headless, gives you all you need